# UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height returning correct number but SKSpriteNode not showing up at top

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm learning `SpriteKit` and trying to use `SKAction.moveToY` to move a node upwards off the screen. I wanted to first get it to just get close to the top (I assume once I get it to the top part of the node will be still on screen and I'll have to adjust but that shouldn't be a problem).

The issue is that I've tried using both `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height` and (inside the `didMoveToView` method) the `SKView`'s bounds.size.height. If I `println` both of them they return the correct value for the top (5s is returning 568.0). When I add that value to `SKAction.moveToY(screenHeightVariable, duration: 2)`, it works correctly and moves the node but it stops about 75% of the way to the top of a 5s and about 90% of the way to the top of 6 plus. Is there a different way I should be getting a Y value for the very top of the screen? Here is some of my code (try to ignore some of the more illogical stuff like red ufo because this is more just learning and trial by error):

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    println(view.bounds.size.height)

    xVal = self.frame.width/2
    ufoNode = ufo(imageNamed: "ufo")
    ufoNode!.position = CGPoint(x: xVal!, y: 30)
    ufoNode!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = charCat


    ufoRedNode = obstacle(imageNamed: "ufo-red")
    ufoRedNode!.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width/2 - 50), y: 30)
    ufoNode!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = sceneCat

    self.addChild(ufoRedNode!)
    self.addChild(ufoNode!)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)



        if location.x < self.frame.width/2 {
            // Left
            direction = Selector("moveLeft:")

        } else {
            // Right
            direction = Selector("moveRight:")

        }

        movementTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.005, target: self, selector: direction!, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.fireBullet(self)
        fireBulletTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "fireBullet:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}

func fireBullet(sender: AnyObject!) {


    var singleBullet: bullet?
    bulletY = ufoNode!.position.y + 10

    if bulletSide == "Left" {
        bulletX = (ufoNode!.position.x - ((ufoNode!.size.width/4) ))
        bulletSide = "Right"
       // println("left")
    } else {
        bulletX = (ufoNode!.position.x + ((ufoNode!.size.width/4) ))
        bulletSide = "Left"
       // println("right")
    }

    singleBullet = bullet(imageNamed: "bullet")
    singleBullet!.position = CGPoint(x: bulletX!, y: bulletY!)
    var bulletAction: SKAction = SKAction.moveToY(screenHeight, duration: 2)


    singleBullet!.runAction(bulletAction)

    self.addChild(singleBullet!)


}
```

Comment: Just solved it by using self.frame.height inside the didMoveToView method and got it to the point I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `position` of the `SKSpriteNode` is by default the midpoint of the sprite. Therefore moving the `node` to `screenHeight`, moves the midpoint of the sprite to `screenHeight`. The lower half of the `node` will be still inside the screen. 
If you want to remove it completely you can try offsetting the final position by `singleBullet.size.height/2`.

```
var bulletAction: SKAction = SKAction.moveToY(screenHeight + singleBullet.size.height/2, duration: 2)
```

You can also reconfigure change the `anchorPoint` property of the `node` to change which point inside the spriteNode is moved to the `position` property of the spriteNode

> **anchorPoint** : Defines the point in the sprite that corresponds to the
>   node’s position. You specify the value for this property in the unit
>   coordinate space. The default value is (0.5,0.5), which means that the
>   sprite is centered on its position.

Also replace your `NSTimer` with `SKActions`. `NSTimers` don't work well with `SpriteKit`. For example.

```
let action = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
    self.fireBullet(self)
}

let timerAction = SKAction.sequence([action,SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)])
let foreverTimer = SKAction.repeatActionForever(timerAction)
self.runAction(foreverTimer)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the distance from the top isn't anywhere near half the height of the node (the node is only 8.5 points tall) and the distance from the top is a couple hundred points. I tried singleBullet.size.height/2 and also singleBullet.size.height*2 for good measure and neither came close.

Comment: also you shouldn't use `NSTimers` in SpriteKit. You can use `SKAction.repeatForever` and `SKAction.waitDuration` to create a repeating action.